# remove fragment on a button touch

Tags: android, android-fragments

I just need to remove a fragment when a button in it is tapped

```
public static class EditNameDialog extends DialogFragment {
    ...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_in_page, container);
        ...
        Button cancelButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        cancelButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                //remove the fragment here
                return false;
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I just need to remove the fragment when the button is tapped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the fragment with use below code:

```
 //remove the fragment from transaction manager
    FragmentManager frgManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = frgManager.findFragmentByTag(tagName);
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = frgManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment).commit();
    }
```

Comment: this work fine. Can you please suggest any way to remove all fragment from activity?

Comment: Please provide your comment on this.

Comment: Hi @VijaySingh please use view.removeAllViews(); to remove all fragment from view of an activity.